# Is there any good spec or library for uri-templating(routing) in java or scala

Tags: java, scala, routes

I'm trying to create a mvc framework for myself in scala. Routers are necessary. I have a route file, contains:

```
/              "App.index"
/users         "Users.index"
/users/{id}    "Users.show"
/articles/{year}/{month}/{day} "Article.list"
```

I need a library to parse the urls and find the best matching.

I know there is one [uri-templates](http://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/), but I hope I can find more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at **Routineer** - Scala DSL for declaring HTTP routes:

https://github.com/mvv/routineer

Comment: I just looked at its code, but is a little harder for me to understand now. Thank you all the same.

Comment: I had never heard of it. +1 for that. :-)

Comment: @Daniel: I can recommend http://implicit.ly/ - you can find all recent Scala library updates there.